# Is there a better way to intersect then union maps?

Tags: haskell

Recently I've come across this pattern several times. Basically it processes all keys in `as` that also exist in `bs` and doesn't touch the other keys.

```
foo :: (a -> b -> a) -> Map a -> Map b -> Map a
foo f as bs = (Map.intersectionWith f as bs) `Map.union` (Map.difference as bs)
```

Due to the nature of `union` this can be shortened to:

```
bar :: (a -> b -> a) -> Map a -> Map b -> Map a
bar f as bs = Map.intersectionWith f as bs `Map.union` as
```

But still this will require three traversals (two over `as` one over `bs`). My intuition is that there should be a ways to solve this with just two traversals.

Comment: Probably the very general [`mergeWithKey`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:mergeWithKey) function can be used for this.

Comment: I'd try to replace the first *(const empty)* by *id* in the example for myIntersectionWithKey given at chi's link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually it is right there: `Map.differenceWith` does right what I want. This is a little bit unintuitive, but basically it takes the actual difference of `as` and `bs` **and** gives the opportunity to include values from the intersection into the resulting set.

Therefore this

```
foo :: (a -> b -> a) -> Map a -> Map b -> Map a
foo f as bs = (Map.intersectionWith f as bs) `Map.union` (Map.difference as bs)
```

can be rewritten as

```
baz :: (a -> b -> a) -> Map a -> Map b -> Map a
baz f as bs = Map.differenceWith (\a b -> Just (f a b)) as bs
```

Simple ... sorry for wasting your time :)